# How to create Kibana index in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have Elstaticsearch and Logstash installed, and am going to install Kibana according to the instruction in: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/setup.html

After the trivial download and extract, Elasticsearch is started, then the next step: *Create the .kibana index with dynamic mapping enabled just for that index*:

```
PUT .kibana
{
    "index.mapper.dynamic": true
}
```

lead me astray. I have no idea at all what it means and what I should do according to this instruction. Faithfully hope someone can give me some hint about it.

Answer (score 2):

Logically `.kibana` index needs dynamic mapping for all its fields.

Here we have two use-cases:

1. `index.mapper.dynamic` is set to `true` which is default behaviour in Elasticsearch: You can skip manually creating `.kibana` index step.
2. `index.mapper.dynamic` is set to `false` in Elasticsearch: You have to manually create `.kibana` index with dynamic mapping enabled.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks avr, as to option 2, how to manually create .kibana index?

Comment: @user1928863, you can create it by executing following curl command on any of elasticsearch node. `curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/.kibana/ -d '{ "index.mapper.dynamic": true }'` . You can find documentation for creating index in elasticsearch here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

This step is only required only if you disabled dynamic mapping of fields in the Elasticsearch.  If you haven't done this, then you can simply start Kibana, and it will automatically create all necessary indices, etc.